# How do I identify the referrer page in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, referrer

In VS2003, I am trying to find out the particular page where the request is coming from. I want to identify the exact aspx page name.

Is there a way to only get the page name or some how strip the page name?

Currently I am using the following instruction...

```
string referencepage = HttpContext.Current.Request.UrlReferrer.ToString();
```

and I get the following result...

"http://localhost/MyPage123.aspx?myval1=3333&myval2=4444;

I want to get the result back with out any query string parameters and be able to identify the page MyPage123.aspx accurately...

How do I do that??

Comment: Who's the one randomly downvoting good answers? Also, @dotnet-practicioner: You need to go back to your old questions and start marking good answers as accepted answers before you ask more questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at the [Segments property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.segments(v=VS.90).aspx) of the URI class (which is what HttpContext.Current.Request.UrlReferrer returns).

Something like `HttpContext.Current.Request.UrlReferrer.Segments[1]` (changing the 1 indexer to get the correct segment you require).

Comment: This is the way to go if you want only the filename, without any directories. Be careful if you use directories and might have a file with the same name in multiple directories.

Answer (score 8):

Instead of calling `.ToString` on the Uri, use the `AbsolutePath` property instead:

```
string referencepage = HttpContext.Current.Request.UrlReferrer.AbsolutePath;
```

This should get you "/MyPage123.aspx" in your case.

Edit: Had LocalPath instead of AbsolutePath by mistake